# Optimizing a nested left join query

Tags: sql-server, join

I am working on a SQL query which contains several joins in it which is as follows.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT GL2.Number1, GL.DEPARTMENT,GL.CLASS,GL.SUBCLASS,GL.LINE, PR.*
    FROM DETAIL A

    LEFT JOIN CATEGORIES CAT ON   A.WEB_ID=CAT.CATEGORY_ID  
    LEFT JOIN GROUP_LINES GL ON 
                                            A.BRAND=GL.MANUFACTURER 
                                            OR  A.A1=GL.Number1 
                                            OR  CAT.A2 =  GL.DEPARTMENT
                                            OR  CAT.A3=  GL.CLASS
                                            OR  CAT.A4= GL.SUBCLASS
                                            OR  CAT.A5= GL.LINE


    LEFT JOIN  RULE_GROUPS RG ON GL.GROUP_ID=RG.GROUP_ID
    LEFT JOIN  RULE_GROUPS RG2 ON RG.RULE_ID=RG2.RULE_ID                                            
    LEFT JOIN  GROUP_LINES GL2 ON RG2.GROUP_ID=GL2.GROUP_ID
    LEFT JOIN  PRICING_RULES PR ON RG.RULE_ID=PR.RULE_ID
    LEFT JOIN  PRICING_ATTRIBUTES PA ON PR.RULE_ID=PA.RULE_ID

WHERE A.INVEN_ID='123456'
```

For some reasons, I do not feel that the above query is written in a best possible way. Is there a way I could re-write the above query in a better way?

Comment: a.  You should `INNER JOIN` the first 3 tables instead of `LEFT JOIN` because your `SELECT` is selecting from `GROUP LINES (GL)` down.

Comment: b.  Not sure why you're left joining to `RULE_GROUPS` twice the way you are.. some schema information and requirements might be helpful

Comment: c. There's really no point in the last `LEFT JOIN` to `PRICING_ATTRIBUTES` since you're not even selecting any information from that table

Comment: Thank you and for comment b, first join would be me some rule_ids and I want to join that again with the same table with the obtained rule_id which returns some group_ids which are in turn used to join with PR

Comment: I think you should start with `GROUP_LINES` then join onto that. I do not think you should start with `[DETAIL]` -- in fact I'm not convinced you even need `[DETAIL]` based on how the query is written (although there may be a need that's not correctly executed). You don't ever return anything from `[DETAIL]` so all it is really doing is limiting you to `[GROUP_LINES]` that have a DETAIL record. Although it's impossible to know based on just your query.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include a WHERE clause Details table acts as a connection for other  tables as the input to the query is in Details table. Please check the updated question

Answer (score 2):

I initially intended to leave this as a comment, but it got too long.

`PR.*` might be returning more fields than you actually need in your result set.  Depending on the size of the table, listing the fields you need explicitly may just be theoretical improvement.

Anyway, if this is returning exactly what you want, I wouldn't try and mess with the query itself.  Even if you do manage to get something that returns the exact same result written in a different way, I would not be surprised at all if when you look at the execution plan it ends up being exactly the same.

I would recommend instead taking your working, known good query, and feeding it to the [Tuning Advisor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174202.aspx), which will figure out how to make the query run faster by creating indexes and statistics and such.  It's a great tool and sometimes the results are almost magical.